# Cron job not run

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a Cron Job to send me an email, but it not run:

```
 #!/bin/bash
TotalMem=$(top -n 1 | grep Mem | awk 'NR==1{print $4}')
UsadoMem=$(top -n 1 | grep Mem | awk 'NR==1{print $8}')
PorcUsado=$(echo "scale=2;($UsadoMem/$TotalMem)*100"|bc)
echo $PorcUsado
UsoCpu=$(top -n 1 | grep Cpu | awk '{print $2}')
echo $UsoCpu

if [ $PorcUsado > 1 ] || [ $UsoCpu > 0 ]; then
   echo MEM: $PorcUsado CPU: $UsoCpu|mail -s "Recursos" "mymail@gmail.com"
fi
```

I configure in `crontab -e`:

```
* ** * * peter sh /home/peter/scripts/check.sh
```

The scripts runs normally directly via bash, but i not receive any email via cron

I appreciate any help

Comment: `* * * * *` not `* ** * *`. That format seems invalid.

Comment: I fix it and not running yet :(

Comment: While you're running a script of your own this isn't really a programming question and would be better suited on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions or https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux ...

Comment: @tink, the problem can be in my code. It's a legitimate programming question

Comment: If your script runs in the shell (and I'd expect it to, just glancing over it), it's a  cron usage question; see my answer to your question.

Comment: Please update your question to show the actual contents of your cron file, as pointed out by tadman. Also, you show a space in front of the `#!` at the top of your bash script; if that space is really there, your script will probably be executed by `/bin/sh`. Does the `mail s ...` command work on the command line?

Comment: @PedroAntônio - did you get this resolved in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Lose the **peter**. That syntax is only valid for /etc/crontab, user crontabs created/edited with `crontab -e` don't have the user name in them. And if you have `chmod +x`'d your script you don't need `sh` either.

```
* * * * * /home/peter/scripts/check.sh
```

P.S.:  You could simplify your script drastically, save on the greps, two awks and bc ...

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r UsoCpu PorcUsado <<< "$(  top -n 1 | awk '/Cpu/{printf "%s\t", $2} /Mem/ {printf "%.2f\n", ($8 / $4)*100 ; nextfile}')"
if [ $PorcUsado > 1 ] || [ $UsoCpu > 0 ]; then
   echo MEM: $PorcUsado CPU: $UsoCpu
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cron should look like this:

```
* * * * * peter sh /home/peter/scripts/check.sh
```

Hopefully that should run now.

Comment: Not running yet :(

Comment: Have you set permissions for user Peter to execute? Why have you put ‘sh’ in your cron?

Comment: Peter's have the permissions `-rwxr-xr-x `. The `sh` was inserted in a attemp to work...I remove and not work yet...

Comment: vim /etc/crontab: use * * * * * Peter /home/peter/scripts/check.sh